# MySQL sum of sum variable

Tags: mysql

I am going to sum the `totalSale` variable and store it as `balanced`:

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  sum((price * content.owner_percent) / 100) AS totalSale,
  sum(totalSale) as balanced
FROM customer_content
  INNER JOIN content ON content.id = customer.content_id
WHERE content_owner_id = 3;
```

How can i do this?!

Comment: The sum of the sum equals the sum

Comment: How can i do this? Please help me instead of down voting.

Comment: You could start by clarifying your question. Provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result. And don't tell other contributors how they should vote.

Comment: Your `totalSale` is already giving that value which you require in `balanced`.

Comment: please explain if you need something different.

Comment: You want to count all average (totalSale) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm right, you want to get sum of average (`totalSale`).
If yes, you can do like this:

```
SELECT sum(src.totalSale) as balanced
FROM (
   SELECT
     sum((price * content.owner_percent) / 100) AS totalSale,
   FROM customer_content
   INNER JOIN content ON content.id = customer.content_id
   WHERE content_owner_id = 3
) AS src
```